# DLL load failed(unable to import tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

This's my first time to ask question on stack overflow, thanks for the browse of my question!
  While I'm trying to debug a program(written in python) in Visual Studio Code, as I enter "python .\dnn_example.py", it doesn't output the result, but blocked out this message(the white frame, and it means "which software do I prefer to use to open the file):[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FUIk.png)

Then I saw a message from "PROBLEMS":[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evWmt.png)
It reads "unable to import tensorflow".
  I'm keep trying fixing the problem, thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show your code, and explain more specifically what do you want to do

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not installed tensorflow. Try installing it using conda by `conda install tensorflow` or if you don't use conda, install it using pip by `pip install tensorflow`. 
If you want to run tensorflow on GPU then follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@soumyadipmajumder/complete-guide-to-tensorflow-gpu-installation-on-windows-10-36e5858640e9).